# Multivariable Calculus: Line Integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

I have this math problem. It states:

> Calculate the given line integral $\oint _c {M dx+Ndy}$ where $C$ is
>   the triangle with vertices $P_0=(0, 1)$, $P_1=(2, 1)$, $P_2=(3, 4)$
>   with counterclockwise rotation.

Here is the problem: 
$\oint _c {x dx+ dy}$

---

I'm not sure as to what the "counterclockwise rotation" means. I'm assuming I have to start by finding 3 different line integrals. So I find three parametric lines...

$\vec{P_0} + \vec{P_0P_1}t=<0, 1> + <2t, 0> = <2t, 1>$

$\vec{P_1} + \vec{P_1P_2}t=<2, 1> + <t, 3t> = <2+t, 1+3t>$

$\vec{P_2} + \vec{P_2P_0}t=<3, 4> + <-3t, -3t> = <3-3t, 4-3t>$

That's pretty much where I got. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without appealing to Green's Theorem we proceed.

Inasmuch as this is a closed-path integral,

$$\oint_C (xdy+dy) =\left(\frac12 x^2 +y\right)|_{P_i}^{P_i}=0$$

where $P_i$ is any starting point of the path.

---

Now let's show this explicitly by evaluating each contribution of the line integral.

First segment:

Start at $P_0$ and end at $P_1$.  Parameterize the curve as $x=t$, $y=1$, with $0\le t\le 2$.  Then, $dx=dt$ and $dy=0$.  Thus, we have

$$\int_{C_{1}} (xdx+dy) = \int_0^2 tdt = 2$$

Second segment:

Start at $P_1$ and end at $P_2$.  Parameterize the curve as $x=t+2$, $y=3t+1$, with $0\le t\le 1$.  Then, $dx=dt$ and $dy=3dt$.  Thus, we have

$$\int_{C_{2}} (xdx+dy) = \int_0^1 ((t+2)+3)dt = 11/2$$

Third segment:

Start at $P_2$ and end at $P_3$.  Parameterize the curve as $x=3-3t$, $y=4-3t$, with $0\le t\le 1$.  Then, $dx=-3dt$ and $dy=-3dt$.  Thus, we have

$$\int_{C_{3}} (xdx+dy) = \int_0^1 (3-3t+1)(-3)dt = -15/2$$

Thus, summing the contributions reveals that

$$\oint_C (xdx+dy) = 2+11/2-15/2=0$$

as expected!

Comment: How would a contour help with this problem? Sorry just never heard of the term to be honest.

Comment: @KFC The line integral is an integration along a path (or contour).  I added  a section in which we evaluate the closed line integral directly.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: How did you decide the bounds for each $t$?

Comment: Well, the parameterization is not unique.  For Paths 2 and 3, we kept things simple and used $0\le t \le 1$.  On Path 1, we first let $x=t$ (recall that $y=1$ here) and thus $0\le t \le 2$.  If you like, we can change Path 1 so that $0\le t \le 1$ and $x=2t$.

Comment: So why couldn't $0\leq t \leq1$, be for all 3 paths? Sorry for all the questions, I'm trying to apply this to other problems as well.

Comment: So, how do you get $0\leq t \leq 2$ with $x=t$ and $y=1$?

Comment: @KFC Remember that parameterization is not unique.  One can choose any legitimate way that works.  For the case of line segments, it is always possible to have $0\le t\le 1$.  Would you prefer that I change Path 1 so that $0\le t\le 1$ and $x=2t$?  The result is the same.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think that "counterclockwise rotation" just means do the line integral starting from point 1, going in order which would take you counterclockwise around the triangle. So I think what you're doing is right

Answer (score 1):

By Green's Theorem,
$$\int_{C} x\,dx+1\,dy=\iint_{T}\left(\frac{\partial 1}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)d A=\iint_T 0\,dA=0.$$

Comment: My class hasn't learned that yet, it's not until 3 more sections

Comment: Is there another way to do it? I don't think I'm supposed to use Green's Theorem.

Comment: @KFC Ok sorry. Then you have to compute three separated integrals as you started to do.

Comment: @Spenser Actually, the line integral can be evaluated without appeal to Green's Theorem or without evaluating each of the three contributions separately.  Just note that this is a closed path.  So, $\oint_C (xdx+dy) =(x^2/2+y)|_P^P=0$, where $P$ is any point on the path.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that your field is a conservative one as $\;\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y}=0=\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\;$ , with $\;P=x\;,\;\;Q=1\;$ , and thus the integral equals zero on any simple, "nice" closed path.

You can also observe that

$$\;(x,1)=\nabla\left(\frac12x^2\,,\,y\right)$$

Comment: How does $\;(x,1)=\nabla\left(\frac12x^2\,,\,y\right)$ help?

Comment: @KFC Do you know what the gradient of function is?

Comment: It's just the derivative, right?

Comment: Wrt each variable in the coordinates...yes.